# How to change value in dataframe column?

Tags: python, replace

I try to change a value of a column (named Q10) of my dataframe named Test (dtype is object) : 24:00 needs to be converted to 23:59. However, python does not seem to recognize the value 24:00. When I type

`'24:00' in Test['Q10']`
it gives False as output, while I know the first value is equal to 24:00. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`a=Test['Q10']`
a is `pandas.core.series.Series`
To access value in dataframe, you can use `.values`
so `'24:00' in a.values` returns `True`

Regarding update `24:00` to `23:59`, assuming the row number for this cell is `2`, you can use `.at`

```
Test.at[2, 'Q10']= '23:59'
```

Now, if you print `Test` again, it would be

|  | Q10 | Others |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 24:00 | 1 |
| 1 | 24:00 | 2 |
| 2 | 23:59 | 1 |

More on `pandas.DataFrame.at` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html)